# How can i give reward to users on IronSource Rewarded Video?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rewardedvideoad, ironsource

I have two scenes in my project. There is only one award-winning video for each scene.
In first scene, Everthing is okey, but if you come to second scene to first scene, i can't give reward to users and endofRewarded panel is not visible. What is the correct method for giving reward? How can i do that?

P.s : I know the tutorial is here.
https://developers.ironsrc.com/ironsource-mobile/unity/rewarded-video-integration-unity/

But, I am beginner.
Thank you.

Here is my code for first scene :

```
public class RewardedMain : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string appkey;

    public GameObject endofRewarded, anaEkran;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        IronSource.Agent.shouldTrackNetworkState(true);
        IronSourceEvents.onRewardedVideoAvailabilityChangedEvent += RewardedVideoAvaibilityChangedEvent;
        IronSourceEvents.onRewardedVideoAdClosedEvent += RewardedVideoAdClosedEvent;
        IronSourceEvents.onRewardedVideoAdRewardedEvent += RewardedVideoAdRewardedEvent;

        //IronSourceEvents.onRewardedVideoAdReadyEvent += OnRewardedVideoAdReady;


    }//END START

    public void showRewarded()
    {
        if (IronSource.Agent.isRewardedVideoAvailable())
        {
            anaEkran.SetActive(false);
            IronSource.Agent.showRewardedVideo("MainRewarded");
        }

      
    }

    void RewardedVideoAdClosedEvent()
    {
        IronSource.Agent.init(appkey, IronSourceAdUnits.REWARDED_VIDEO);
        IronSource.Agent.shouldTrackNetworkState(true);

    }

    void RewardedVideoAvaibilityChangedEvent(bool available)
    {
        bool rewardedVideoAvailability = available;
    }

    void RewardedVideoAdRewardedEvent(IronSourcePlacement ssp)
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("totalCoin", PlayerPrefs.GetInt("totalCoin") + 150);
        GameObject.Find("GoldNumberText").GetComponent<Text>().text = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("totalCoin").ToString();
        SoundManager.Instance.PlayEarnGoldSound();
        endofRewarded.SetActive(true);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what your project looks like, so I'll give some hints as per the information you've given me now.
The problem you're having is that when you get to the second scene, the objects that are hooked up to this mono script will disappear?
If so, add the following code to awake and your GameObject will exist across scenes!

```
DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
```

Comment: It does not work.